# NuGet.org how to specify GPL3 license?

Tags: c#, nuget

When creating a NuGet package how do I specify the GPL3 license?

I tried to add the following to my csproj file:

```
<PackageLicenseExpression>GPLv3</PackageLicenseExpression>
<PackageLicenseExpression>GPL3</PackageLicenseExpression>
```

Nuget.org can't recognize any of those.

But the following does work:

`<PackageLicenseExpression>MIT</PackageLicenseExpression>`

Comment: https://spdx.org/licenses/